# Auto Re-size Images on Web Pages

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button type button that I will like to place an image over. My code looks like this

```
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="bus()">
  <img src="DestinationH-Bus-Driver-Login.png">
</button>
```

The problem with this is that I get a gray space that makes the overall image to large, if I use a larger image it works fine. But if I call the site from a phone suddenly the big buttons are to small to see. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

I know about type image but I can't use that because it gives me a button of submit type and I want a button of button type, however the pic does work excellent if I use the image type but not the above method.

Comment: We're working blind. Show us some code.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just put the `onclick` event on the image?

```
<img src="DestinationH-Bus-Driver-Login.png" onClick="bus()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If necessary, you could use an `input` tag of type image and cancel the default form submission in the event handler by returning `false`:

```
<input type="image" src="DestinationH-Bus-Driver-Login.png" onclick="bus(); return false;"/>
```

That should give you the same functionality as a `button` tag, but with better cross-browser support for styling it with an image.